# php script which echo text betwen 1st P tags and echo 2nd p tags as another variable

Tags: php, regex, parsing

i have text in mysql databas like:

```
<p>text text test text</p>
<p>demo demo demo</p>
```

i'd like to write php script to echo "text text test text" in a variable and echo "demo demo demo"  in another variable

Comment: Not clear what you want actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$charsToRemove =   array('<p>','</p>');
$modifyString  =   str_ireplace($charsToRemove ,'',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want the values from the database to be displayed?

then,

if you are using mysql,

```
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT colName FROM tableName");
  if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
     $ret = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
     echo $ret['colName'];
  }
```

Comment: ^ Don't use mysql_* functions; the deprecation process has begin, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html="<p>text text test text</p><p>demo demo demo</p>";
preg_match_all("'<p>(.*?)</p>'si", $html, $match);
if ($match) {
    $var1 = $match[1][0];
    $var2 = $match[1][1];
}
echo $var1."\n";
echo $var2."\n";
?>
```

Do you have just two < p > tags? If not you need to loop the $match[1] array to retrieve all.